# problemas al generar un WebService

Tags: php, webservice, soap

**server.php**

```
    require_once('DB.php');

$uri = "http://localhost/dwes18/distancia/E7/version1/web2";
$server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => $uri));

$server->setClass("DB");
$server->handle();
```

**cliente.php**

```
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$url = "http://localhost/dwes18/distancia/E7/version1/web2/server.php";
$uri = "http://localhost/dwes18/distancia/E7/version1/web2";


    $cliente = new SoapClient(null, array('encoding'=>'UTF8','location' => $url, 'uri' => $uri));

    $nombre = $cliente->getSaberNombre('IAWASIR');
```

y clase DB.php

```
class DB {

    public function getSaberNombre($cod) {
        $nombre = null;
        try {
            $dwes = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=agl", "root", "");
            $dwes->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $nombre = -($e->getCode());
            return $nombre;
        }
        if (!isset($error)) {
            $sql = "SELECT nombre FROM modulo WHERE cod='$cod'";
            $resultado = $dwes->query($sql);
            if ($resultado) {
                $row = $resultado->fetch();
                $nombre = $row['nombre'];
            }
        }
        return $nombre;
    }





}
```

y no hace más que darme este error

> SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: string
>   'Implantaci\xf3...' is not a valid utf-8 string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dwes18\distancia\E7\version1\web1\cliente.php:12 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dwes18\distancia\E7\version1\web1\cliente.php(12):
>   SoapClient->__call('getSaberNombre', Array) #1 {main}

alguna idea?

Comment: quita el `charset=UTF-8`

Comment: quito ese y me sale Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document

Comment: y la cosa es que es sin xml

Answer (score -1):

solución encontrada

tan fácil como añadir a la variable $opciones los valores suficientes para que los datos no causen excepcion.

```
public function getSaberNombre($cod) {
    $nombre = null;
    try {

        $opciones = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8', PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $dwes = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=agl2", "root", "", $opciones);
        $dwes->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $nombre = -($e->getCode());
        return $nombre;
    }
    if (!isset($error)) {
        $sql = "SELECT nombre FROM modulo WHERE cod='$cod'";
        $resultado = $dwes->query($sql);
        if ($resultado) {
            $row = $resultado->fetch();
            $nombre = $row['nombre'];
        }
    }
    return $nombre;
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar en que consiste esa solucion encontrada?  Mira [answer] para mejorar la respuesta. un saludo

Comment: tan fácil como añadir a la variable $opciones los valores suficientes para que los datos no causen excepcion.

Comment: añadirlo en la pregunta,no en los comentarios. Un saludo